# Normalizing data and inverse

Tags: matlab

I use the following code to normalise my data in MATLAB:

```
Data=[130 100 100 100 300 300 30 300 30 320 200 50 300 25 100 250 1200 300 320 300 100 100 170 500 1000 200 120 450 200 2100 100 100 100 3450 500 30 100 550 4000 150 500 380 400 4000 180 540 700 100 500 2300 200 200 50 2000 400 100 50 50 100 4000 4000 3250 100 100 100 100 3300 100 100 4020 150 150 2300 3000 100 50 100 50 100 200 2000 300]

Data=randn(100,1); 
%Histogram with histfit 
nbins=20; 
h=histfit(Data,nbins); 
[nelements,bincenters]=hist(Data,nbins); 
hold on %histogram computed manually and scaled with trapz() 
avg=mean(Data); 
stdev=std(Data); 
x=sort(Data); 
y=exp(-0.5*((x-avg)/stdev).^2)/(stdev*sqrt(2*pi));     
plot(x,y*trapz(bincenters,nelements),'g','LineWidth',1.5)     
legend('Histogram','Distribution from hisfit','Distribution computed manually')
```

It works well, I found the mean and standard deviation. Now, I try to inverse the `y` values with `ln` to find back the original points, but, I was not successful. Could you please give any idea to inverse `y` values?

Comment: The inverse of `exp` is `log`. Can you show us the code you used for the inverse?

Comment: Not sure what you are actually trying to accomplish here - do you want to map some measured data in Data to a normal distribution? In this case you need to compute the empirical CDF from the data and use the error function (i.e. CDF of normal PDF) to map it to a corresponding normal value.

Comment: my datas are related drug demand for hospital.The demand distribution does not normal.I used above code to normalize data. Now, I want to inverse original point.y value, stdev and avg comes from normalized data. avg=0.0326 stdev=0.9593
xinverse=log(-0,5*((y-avg)/stdev.^2/stdev*sqrt(2*pi)); I got some value but

Comment: my datas are related drug demand for hospital.The demand distribution does not normal.I used above code to normalize data. Now, I want to inverse original point.y value, stdev and avg comes from normalized data. avg=0.0326 stdev=0.9593
xinverse=log(-0,5*((y-avg)/stdev.^2/stdev*sqrt(2*pi)); I got some value but I did not get a reasonable result.